# Configuring JRebel 5 with Resin 3.1.x on mac

Tags: java, classloader, resin, jrebel

I'm evaluating `JRebel`, I was able to install and test it on tomcat in few minutes but I've spent hours trying to configure it with Resin 3.1. 
I'm geting the following error in the app server log:

```
#############################################################

JRebel Resin installation problem!

See http://www.zeroturnaround.com/resin-problem/ or consult with the installation manual for correct JRebel installation with Resin server.

#############################################################
```

and when I navigate to the indicated url: http://www.zeroturnaround.com/resin-problem/ I received a `404 page not found`.

I was able to redeploy jsps but class are never instrumented by JRebel (but they are correctly monitored by jrebel, as stated in the jrebel.log). 
Simply executing the web app doesn't trigger monitored class instrumentation and reloading.

I read about an issue with the Resin class loader (SystemClassLoader) and JRebel instrumentation but I don't understand how to configure JRebel to solve it and the cited url about resin-problem is not available.

Was anybody able to integrate JRebel with Resin 3.1.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you configure -javaagent argument?

Should be configured like this:

http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel-reference-manual/server.html#server-4.6.26

Comment: Thanks it works! My issue was that I tried to attach JRebel agent to resin WatchDog process using **resin.conf** (using <watchdog-arg>) because it is more problematic in our dev env to modify httpd.sh. Do you know if it is possible to integrate JRebel and Resin 3.1+ without touching httpd.sh (using resin.conf or in some other ways)? Thanks again

Comment: It was possible to do what you wanted with Resin versions older than 3.1 (also described in the manual), however I can't really tell you the reason right now as I would have to dig the reason in the history, sorry.